# Prove infimum of a quantity is fact greater than zero in Euclid space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

Assume ${a_i} \in {\mathbb R^3},i = 1,2,3 $

$a_1, a_2, a_3\text{ are not in the same line}$

Prove that:

\begin{array}{l}
\inf \left\{ {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^3 {\left\| {x_i - {a_i}} \right\|} \left| {x_i \in \text{a line}} \right.}, i=1,2,3 \right\} > 0
\end{array}

Infimum is taken on every line of $\mathbb R^3$.

I tried but I cannot prove. I am not sure that whether the statement is true. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by $x \in \text{a line}$?

Comment: I take infimium on every line of R^3. A line is determined by two points in a space.

Comment: Do you allow say $x_1 = x_2$, in which case the points are automatically on a line, or do you exclude that as a degenerate case?  What about $x_1 = x_2 = x_3$ in which case the points are on infinitely many lines?

Comment: Yeb, it can be $x_1 =x_2 = x_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f : (\mathbb{R}^3)^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the objective function $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \lVert x_i - a_i \rVert$.  Then, notice that for each $i,j$, we have that $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) \to \infty$ as $|(x_i)_j| \to \infty$, regardless of the behavior of the other components of vectors.  Therefore, there is some $A$ such that for $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ outside $(B_A(0))^3$ (where $B_A(0)$ is the closed box $[-A, A]^3 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$) we have $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) > f(0, 0, 0)$.

Now, $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are colinear if and only if the cross product $(x_2 - x_1) \times (x_3 - x_1) = 0$.  This gives a system of three algebraic equations in the coordinates of $x_1, x_2, x_3$, which therefore cuts out a closed subset of $(\mathbb{R}^3)^3$.  Now, intersecting this with $(B_A(0))^3$ gives a compact subset of $(\mathbb{R}^3)^3$, so $f$ restricted to this subset achieves a minimum value.  By the assumption that $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are not colinear, this minimum value must be greater than 0; and by the previous observations, this minimum value is equal to the overall minimum value of $f$ on $\{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in (\mathbb{R}^3)^3 \mid (x_2 - x_1) \times (x_3 - x_1) = 0 \}$.

Comment: I think your answer is True. Your answer is beautiful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your answer is true in a finite dimension space but can you prove that in a infinite Hilbert space? I think it is difficult because we do know whether the constrain is weak closed.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of the set of which you are taking the infimum are obviously real numbers greater or equal than zero. So it is enough to show that the infimum is not zero.

Suppose that it is indeed zero. Since that element (as well as any other) is calculated via a sum which terms are $\|x_i - a_i\| \geq 0$ then it follows that every term must be zero, yielding $x_i = a_i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$. But that is an absurdity since the $x_i$ are in the same line and the $a_i$ are not. Therefore the infimum is not zero.

Comment: Your answer  is minimum not Infimum. Maybe there is no line for your answer. See the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{{{e^x}}}$, its infimum is 0 but no x satisfies. Your answer need a line like argmin of the problem. I cannot prove whether minimization problem has solution.

Comment: Yes you are right, I assumed that minimum exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is true:

If the $a_i$
are not on a line,
then,
by the triangle inequality,
$\|a_i-a_j\|
\lt \|a_i-a_k\|+\|a_j-a_k\|
$
for all permutations of
${1, 2, 3}$.

Let 
$d = \min(\|a_i-a_k\|+\|a_j-a_k\|-\|a_i-a_j\|)
$
over all permutations of
${1, 2, 3}$.
Then,
if the $x_i$
are on a line,
$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^3 \left\| {x_i - {a_i}} \right\| 
\ge d
$.

I have the start of a proof,
but I don't see how to complete it.
Perhaps someone can do that.

Start of proof.

If the $x_i$ are on a line,
then
$\|x_i-x_j\|
= \|x_i-x_k\|+\|x_j-x_k\|
$
for some permutation of
${1, 2, 3}$,
so that
$x_k = tx_i + (1-t)x_j$
for some $0 < t < 1$.
Assume this is true for
$i=1, j=2, k=3$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
D
&=\sum\limits_{i = 1}^3 \left\| x_i - a_i \right\|\\
&=\| x_1 - a_1 \|+\| {x_2 - a_2} \|+\| {x_3 - a_3} \| \\
&=\| x_1 - a_1 \|+\| x_2 - a_2 \|+\| tx_1 + (1-t)x_2 - a_3 \| \\
&=\| x_1 - a_1 \|+\| x_2 - a_2 \|+\| t(x_1-a_3) + (1-t)(x_2 - a_3) \| \\
\end{array}
$

At this point,
I don't know what to do.
I think that
the reverse triangle inequality
might be usable,
but how is not clear to me.

So,
I'll stop here.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think I can continue your proving. Hint: I use Lipshitz property of projection mapping on the line. Example: ${\left\| {{a_1} - {a_2}} \right\|^2} \ge {\left\| {\Pi ({a_1}) - \Pi ({a_2})} \right\|^2}$